# rails: Why is content-type default to javascript/text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently when i curl my root url the content type is returned as `text/javascript`

`curl -I https://foo.bar.com/`

returned is `Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8`

When I visit in chrome it shows as expected:

`Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8`

the root controller action *does* respond to both html and js depending on request type.

```
if request.xhr?
  render partial: "item", collection: @listings, as: :listing, layout: false
end
```

**Question:** How can I make the default response be HTML and maintain the current functionality where the controller responds to xhr without appending html filetype?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send what type you are expecting. Chrome sends

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

So add `-H Accept:text/html` to your curl request and then see what it returns. Rails uses Javascript for AJAX and [Turbolinks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks).

Comment: I updated my question. How do i change the default rails response to be text/html instead of text/javascript without appending html extension

Comment: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render, "2.2.12 Options for render". Render an empty file and set the content type to 'text/html'. Also see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action. If you only have a `.js` file in your view, it will render `Content-Type: application/javascript`. Try adding a `.html` or `.html.erb` file in your view. Also see '2.2.7 Rendering HTML' and try `render html: ""`.